# Plotly Static Image Export gets OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, plotly, orca

Getting this error every time I run my code. I've tried make it work but it just won't stop giving me this error.

```py
if not os.path.exists('images'):
    os.mkdir('images')
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
N = 100
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
sz = np.random.rand(N) * 30

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker={'size': sz, 'color': colors, 'opacity': 0.6,
                'colorscale': 'Viridis'})
pio.write_image(fig, r'images\fig1.png')
```

I just want to be able to export the images.

Comment: Can you add the error message you are facing ?

Comment: it's in the title

Comment: Same problem -- I tride to use conda to install orca, but got an error about requests being a dependency of conda and can't be removed (went through a whole bunch of steps of pip uninstalling requests etc, no luck). So I installed Node and npm (64 bit), used that to install orca, and then got this error. So I uninstalled Node and npm 64 bit, then reinstalled using Node 32 bit. Still getting this exact same error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After posting my comment above I went further down the rabbit hole.

In the end I uninstalled orca from npm. I updated my conda with `conda update conda`, completely uninstalled plotly and plotly-conda, and then finally did a `pip install plotly`, and `conda install -c plotly plotly-orca`.

For some reason this led conda to do to a massive update of *all* of my packages (including deleting some like pandas). So far this hasn't broken any old code, and plotly-orca works. Insert eyeroll emoji here. I really hope it works for you.